# Spring Boot MVC to allow any kind of content-type in controller

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mybatis, media-type

I have a `RestController` that multiple partners use to send XML requests. However this is a legacy system that it was passed on to me and the original implementation was done in a very loose way in PHP.

This has allowed to clients, that now they refuse to change, to send different `content-types` (`application/xml`, `text/xml`, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) and it has left me with the need to support many `MediaTypes` to avoid returning **415** MediaType Not Supported Errors.

I have used the following code in a configuration class to allow many media types.

```
@Bean
public MarshallingHttpMessageConverter marshallingMessageConverter() {
    MarshallingHttpMessageConverter converter = new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setMarshaller(jaxbMarshaller());
    converter.setUnmarshaller(jaxbMarshaller());
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,
            MediaType.TEXT_XML, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED, MediaType.ALL));
    return converter;
}

@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxbMarshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(CouponIssuedStatusDTO.class, CouponIssuedFailedDTO.class,
            CouponIssuedSuccessDTO.class, RedemptionSuccessResultDTO.class, RedemptionResultHeaderDTO.class,
            RedemptionFailResultDTO.class, RedemptionResultBodyDTO.class, RedemptionDTO.class, Param.class,
            ChannelDTO.class, RedeemRequest.class);
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.setMarshallerProperties(props);
    return marshaller;
}
```

The controller method is this:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/request", produces = { "application/xml;charset=UTF-8" }, consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<RedemptionResultDTO> request(
        @RequestHeader(name = "Content-Type", required = false) String contentType,
        @RequestBody String redeemRequest) {
    return requestCustom(contentType, redeemRequest);

}
```

This endpoint is hit by all clients. It is only one last client giving me trouble. They are sending `content-type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=65001 (UTF-8)": 65001 (UTF-8)`

Due to the way the charset is sent, Spring Boot refuses to return anything but **415**. Not even `MediaType.ALL` seems to have any effect.

Is there a way to make Spring allow this to reach me ignoring the content-type? Creating a filter and changing the content type was not feasible since the `HttpServletRequest` is not allowing to mutate the content-type. I am out of ideas but I really think there has to be a way to allow custom content-types.

**UPDATE**

If I remove the `@RequestBody` then I don't get the error 415 but I have no way to get the request body since the HttpServletRequest reaches the Controller action empty.

Answer (score 1):

You best case is to remove the `consumes` argument from the `RequestMapping` constructor. The moment you have it added, spring will try to parse it into known type `MediaType.parseMediaType(request.getContentType())` & which tries to create a `new MimeType(type, subtype, parameters)` and thus throws exception due to invalid charset format being passed.

However, if you remove the `consumes`, and you wanna validate/restrict the incoming `Content-Type` to certain type, you can inject `HttpServletRequest` in your method as parameter, and then check the value of `request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE)`.

You also have to remove the `@RequestBody` annotation so Spring doesn't attempt to parse the content-type in attempt to unmarshall the body. If you directly attempt to read the `request.getInputStream()` or `request.getReader()` here, you will see null as the stream has already been read by Spring. So to get access to input content, use spring's `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` inject using `Filter` and then you can later repeatedly read the content as it's cached & not reading from original stream.

I am including some code snippet here for reference, however to see executable example, you can refer my [github](https://github.com/amithkumarg/restapi-springboot-jpa) repo. Its a spring-boot project with maven, once you launch it, you can send your post request to http://localhost:3007/badmedia & it will reflect you back in response `request content-type & body`. Hope this helps.

```
@RestController
public class BadMediaController {

        @PostMapping("/badmedia")
        @ResponseBody
        public Object reflect(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            JsonNode rootNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
            ((ObjectNode) rootNode).put("contentType", request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE));
            String body = new String(((ContentCachingRequestWrapper) request).getContentAsByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            body = URLDecoder.decode(body, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
            ((ObjectNode) rootNode).put("body", body);
            return mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(rootNode);
        }
    }


@Component
public class CacheRequestFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest cachedRequest
                = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest);
        //invoke caching
        cachedRequest.getParameterMap();
        chain.doFilter(cachedRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}
```

Comment: This did not work. I did not have consumes originally and added to see if it would help.

Comment: The same one. 415. If I ommit the @RequestBody then I don't get this error. But I have no way to get the request payload because if the HttpServletRequest has a null inputStream

Comment: Yes you can't have `@RequestBody` annotation, as again spring will try to parse the content type to rightly parse the body. And the reason you are receiving null inputStream with inject `HttpServletRequest` as Spring has already read the body & thus stream is empty. I have updated my solution to give you more assitance with sample code.

Comment: Did the updated solution work for you ? Gives you what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Amith, I will test it as soon as I get back to the office and will update. It does look promising and I really appreciate the answer. It has not been resolved yet so we will try this first thing Monday